# Resuming last activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am totally new to android development....what piece of code shall I write to move back to the last activity from the current activity on a button click?
I use intents to switch between the activities but is there anything specific to resume back on the last activity?
Please advise...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user clicks on Back button, application will automatically take you to previous Activity. You don't need to do anything.

If what you pretend is to implement that action from current Activity, for example through a Back menu option, just call finish() in your Activity. You can call setResult before that, if you called that activity with startActivityForResult

Ger

Comment: I appreciate...but does this back button appear on its own on the called activity...if so please tell me how?

Comment: No, back button is a hard key on your phone

Comment: You can however implement your own Back option/Button, adding a back option to your menu/Activity

Comment: ok...if i want to implement the same on an instance of Button..can I do that?

Comment: @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
          // implement your override logic here
         return;
      }
I found this...how to implement this??

Comment: Yes you can do it. Just add the button to your xml Layout and implement the Button listener. There in the listener just call finish();

Comment: The onBackPressed is a method you can implement in case you want to do something before performing the back action. For example, though not recommended, display a dialog popup asking the user if he really wants to leave the view

Comment: calling finish(); worked for me...so basically on moving back i wanted to remain in onresume only...it achieves that...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the back button should do that "out of the box"...

Answer (score 0):

By default back resume previous activity.

You should read this to better understand android Activities:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles